# How do I "get write permission for device files" in Linux?

Tags: permissions, devices, brightness, volume

I have just install brightnessctl to control my screen brightness, but can only run it as root. Doing otherwise prints the suggestion I "get write permission for device files". What is the correct way to do this? I would also like to be able to set volume with amixer without root privileges, which I assume is the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/dvdrw"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Recommended: Configure `sudo` so you can execute it as a normal user.
2. Write a script with suid root to execute brightnessctl. (Don't try to suid root directly on brightnessctl, because assuming you used a package manager, this won't survive the next upgrade) Depending on how you write the script, this may open up a security hole.
3. Identify the device files in question, write udev rules to set permission after creation. Not fun to write or debug.

---

> I would also like to be able to set volume with amixer without root privileges

I can use `amixer` without root privileges just fine, so for this, I'd either suspect some weird setup on your distro/your machine. Or, if your distro is like mine, you have not made your use a member of the group that has permissions to do audio things (`audio` on my distro, just edit `/etc/group`, or use whatever tools your distro has for that).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add yourself to the `video` and the `input` groups, then `brightnessctl` should just work fine. See https://github.com/Hummer12007/brightnessctl/issues/63.